# Selecting language from a drop down - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization

I've been struggling for several days with implementing a combo box to let the user select the language. I'm using MVC 3 and started with [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207602/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part), which embeds the language in the URL. I like that approach, but instead of providing a link for each language, I want to let the user select a language from a drop down list.   I haven't figured out how to redirect the URL to the current location + the new language when the user selects a language.  I naively tried this:

in _Layout.cshtml

```
<li>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectLanguage", "Home", new { url = @Request.RawUrl })) 
    { 
    <select name="lang" id="lang" size="1" onchange="changeLanguage(this)">
        <option value="en">English </option>
        <option value="it">Italian (Italian)</option>
        <option value="es">Español (Spanish)</option>
    </select>
    }
</li>
```

In HomeController.cs

```
static void AddOtherValues(RouteData routeData, RouteValueDictionary destinationRoute)
{
    foreach (var routeInformation in routeData.Values)
    {
        if (routeInformation.Key == GlobalizedRoute.CultureKey)
            continue; //Do not re-add, it will throw, this is the old value anyway.
        destinationRoute.Add(routeInformation.Key, routeInformation.Value);
    }
}

public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string url, string language, RouteData route)
{
    RouteValueDictionary globalizedRouteData = new RouteValueDictionary();
    globalizedRouteData.Add(GlobalizedRoute.CultureKey, language);
    AddOtherValues(RouteData, globalizedRouteData);

    return RedirectToRoute(globalizedRouteData);

}
```

But, silly me, `RouteData` in `SelectLanguage` contains `HomeController` and `SelectLanguage`, not the route data of wherever I was when I selected the new language.  So `SelectLanguage` is infinitely recursive.  What I'd like to do is pass the current `RouteData` to the `SelectLanguage` action whenever the user chooses another language but I haven't figured out how.    Passing in `route = ViewContext.RouteData` to `BeginForm` doesn't work because it's only a string.  (The rendered html for the form in `route=System.Web.Routing.RouteData` which is useless.)   I just found [this article](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1171) that shows how to get the route data into JavaScript and I think that I could inject it into my form (somehow), but is that necessary?  It feels like a needless round trip for the route data.  Am I missing something simple for this approach, or even a simpler solution?

EDIT--Just noticed that the hyperlinks were missing, which makes it hard for anyone to know what I'm talking about.  Added, so hopefully people will start giving input :)